# Google pay isReadyToPay returning wrong value - Synching issue

Tags: java, android, google-pay

I'm using this API in Android application, Where I need to show setup google pay button based on isReadyToPay status, but it is returning wrong value after adding a card in my google account.

It was returning false which is correct as I have not added card in my account, after adding card it should return true but returning false.

Is there issue synching account details?

Comment: We would like to see the code sample showing your usage of API

Comment: It should work similarly on the web. Are you able to reproduce with a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f70e8nx4/)?